# Execute a different function depending on the value type

Tags: haskell

I would like to be able to apply an `Action` to a `Thing` where only some things accept some actions.

```
data Thing  = BoxVal Box | BallVal Ball   deriving (Show)
data Box    = Box  {name :: String}       deriving (Show)
data Ball   = Ball {size :: Int}          deriving (Show)
data Action = SetName String | Resize Int | ToFoo deriving (Show)

applyAction :: Thing -> Action -> Maybe String
applyAction (BoxVal box) a   = actionToBox box a
applyAction (BallVal ball) a = undefined
applyAction _ _ = Nothing

actionToBox :: Box -> Action -> Maybe String
actionToBox b (SetName s) = Just $ s
actionToBox b (ToFoo)     = Just "foo"
actionToBox _ _           = Nothing
```

The code above works (and is not really elegant), but GHCI complains about `Pattern match(es) are overlapped` in `applyAction`. How to get the same functionality without getting the warning?

Comment: Note that since your code only actually produces `Just` values, you can and should drop the `Maybe` altogether and return the value directly.

Comment: This is dummy-code. There could be an un-supported action, the Maybe is needed.

Comment: Note that in Haskell we usually try as much as we can reasonably do to avoid such cases: if a function accepts a `Thing`, it should work on all `Thing`s. Sometimes this can not be done. If possible, we use `Maybe` or some similar thing to report the error. Other times, we are able to remove the unwanted cases from `Thing` so that invalid states can no longer be represented, and `action` is now total (i.e. it never errors out). What is the best idiomatic solution depends on the actual task, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redundant pattern match is this:

```haskell
applyAction _ _ = Nothing
```

`Thing` only defines two constructors, `BoxVal` and `BallVal`, and those are both explicitly handled in the first two pattern matches:

```haskell
applyAction (BoxVal box) a   = actionToBox box a
applyAction (BallVal ball) a = undefined
```

That makes `applyAction _ _` unnecessary. It could never be matched since the first two patterns match all possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Define a class for `applyAction`, then define appropriate instances.

```
data Thing  = BoxVal Box | BallVal Ball   deriving (Show)
data Box    = Box  {name :: String}       deriving (Show)
data Ball   = Ball {size :: Int}          deriving (Show)
data Action = SetName String | Resize Int | ToFoo deriving (Show)

class Actionable x where
    applyAction :: x -> Action -> Maybe String

instance Actionable Box where
    applyAction :: Box -> Action -> Maybe String
    applyAction b (SetName s) = Just s
    applyAction b ToFoo = Just "foo"
    applyAction _ _ = Nothing

instance Actionable Thing where
    applyAction :: Thing -> Action -> Maybe String
    applyAction (BoxVal b) a = applyAction b a
    applyAction _ _ = undefined
```

(The class doesn't directly solve the overlapping-pattern problem, but does save you from needing to come up with new function names. `applyAction` does the right thing depending on the type of its first argument.)

Comment: Thanks for the input! Getting the think-in-haskell right takes some time.

Comment: @Paradiesstaub: it does, but frankly defining classes for everything is _not_ very much in the spirit of Haskell. Only do it if you're actually abstracting over some important concept, otherwise plain functions like you originally had are often a better approach.